# How can I send email with PDF file on my Wix website

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, velo

I want to send the email with PDF file. But the PDF file should automatically generate with the user input value.

I have tried to solve that problem. But I couldn't find customize email field section. For the more, there isn't a feature to send the email with PDF file.

I have tried to inject my own JavaScript and PHP code. But I can't handle my website code. I could see just HTML Dom. And I could add my own HTML and CSS code. In another way, I try to built my own Wix plugin. But I couldn't find a way to built my own plugin.

How can I solve this problem? I want to know is it possible or impossible.

Comment: https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/include-images-documents-in-form-submission-email

So that is a way you can do it via a form with a built in wix platform called corvid. I am uncertain if this requires payment or not. 

Also looks like they have the ability to add code as well: 
https://www.wix.com/blog/2017/12/wix-code-creation-without-limits

Answer (score 0):

Corvid (https://www.wix.com/corvid/) allows you to add javascript to your Wix Site and add custom functionalities. If you want to generate dynamic PDF files based on your site user's input I suggest you use a PDF Generator API, an example of how to implement this can be found here: https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/corvid-tips-and-updates/example-pdf-generator

Comment: Hi Shan. Thanks for your help.  I would like to install npm module but I can't find the site structure section on my wix. could you help me?